# How to trigger Notification in background?

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm trying to trigger a notification every 15 minutes, starting from the time I set. Currently my app notifies only when my application is open or when it is in the recent applications but when i closed my application the notification doesn't work any longer but when i open again my app it will trigger the notification.  Based on my research I need a Service. So I have 3 files.

In my MainActivity, i set the alarm

```
private void scheduleNotification(int week){
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId", getResources().getInteger(R.integer.notification_id));

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, getResources().getInteger(R.integer.notification_id), notificationIntent, 0);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
}
```

in the MainActivity i call a BroadcastReceiver which is the NotificationPublisher. Here is my NotificationPublisher

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

final String TAG = "NotificationPublisher";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent service = new Intent(context, NotificationAlarmService.class);
    service.putExtra("notifId", intent.getIntExtra("notifId", 0));
    context.startService(service);
}
```

then I start a service by using the BroadcastReceiver which is the NotificationAlarmService, here i build a Notification using `NotificationCompat.Builder`.

```
public class NotificationAlarmService extends Service {
. . . . 

 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flag, int startId)
{
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, intent.getIntExtra("notifId", 0), mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("App");
    builder.setContentText("Notify Me");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon());
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(intent.getIntExtra("notifId", 0), builder.build());

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flag, startId);
}
```

I already tried returning `START_STICKY` instead of `super.onStartCommand` I  understand that when i used a service it will run in the background even if the user closed the application. I also tried changing `this` and used `getBaseContext()` in the service but this it doesn't trigger the notification. I don't know if i'm missing something. Thank you in advance.

*EDIT*

Here is my Manifest

```
    <receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".NotificationAlarmService"
        android:enabled="true"> 
    </service>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a week, I finally got it. In my Manifest i put something like this

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".NotificationAlarmService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

i've removed the `enabled="true"` in the receiver and also add `QUICKBOOT_POWERON`. Then add an action in the service which is `NOTIFICATION_SERVICE` and call it in my service like this

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Service in your Manifest file (Same as declaring an Activity) under application tag like this,

```
<service android:name="com.example.android.NotificationAlarmService">
    </service>
```

Comment: i already done that. :( but still it doesn't work. I also include `android:enabled="true"`