# setting the Notification to trigger at a certain user event

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-notifications

So I'm creating this carousel app and I was working on the notifications. i was able to create the notification and have it pop up when the fragment starts, but what I'm trying to do is have the notification pop up every 20 swipes or so.

[image]

Here's the code for the Notifications

The Fragment

```
class MainFragment: Fragment() {

//    private lateinit var manager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2
    private var counter: Int = 0
    private var pageChangeCallback: ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback? = null


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: MainFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.main_fragment,
            container, false)

        viewPager = binding.imageSlider


        val data: MutableList<CarouselItem> = ArrayList()
        data.add(CarouselItem(1, bcw_65, "First"))
        data.add(CarouselItem(2, bcw_66, "Second"))
        data.add(CarouselItem(3, bcw_67, "Third"))
        data.add(CarouselItem(4, bcw_68, "Fourth"))
        data.add(CarouselItem(5, bcw_69, "Fifth"))
        data.add(CarouselItem(6, bcw_70, "Sixth"))
        data.add(CarouselItem(2, bcw_71, "Seventh"))

        viewPager.adapter = CarouselItemAdapter(data, viewPager)

        viewPager.clipToPadding = false
        viewPager.clipChildren = false
        viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3
        viewPager.getChildAt(0).overScrollMode = RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER

        val compositePageTransformer = CompositePageTransformer()
        compositePageTransformer.addTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(30))
        compositePageTransformer.addTransformer { page, position ->
            val r = 1 - abs(position)
            page.scaleY = 0.85f + r * 0.25f
        }

        viewPager.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer)


        //Used to count the number of swipes bing called
        viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                counter++
                binding.counterView.text = counter.toString()
            }
        }.also { pageChangeCallback = it })

        createChannel(
            getString(R.string.carousel_notification_id),
            getString(R.string.app_name)

        )

            val notificationManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService(
                requireContext(),
                NotificationManager::class.java,
            ) as NotificationManager

            notificationManager.sendNotification(
                requireContext().getText(R.string.swipe_description).toString(), requireContext()
            )




        return binding.root
    }

    //Needed to destroy the pageChangeCallback
    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        viewPager.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback!!)
        pageChangeCallback = null
    }

    private fun createChannel (channelID: String, channelName: String){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                channelID,
                channelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )

            notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
            notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.WHITE
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
            notificationChannel.description = getString(R.string.swipe_description)

            val notificationManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(
                NotificationManager::class.java
            )

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }
    }


}
```

Notification Utils

```
private val NOTIFICATION_ID = 0



fun NotificationManager.sendNotification(messageBody: String, applicationContext: Context) {

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
        applicationContext,
        applicationContext.getString(R.string.carousel_notification_id)
    )

        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.with_outline_6)
        .setContentTitle(applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText(messageBody)


    notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())


}
```

I know there is probably an easy solution that I am not seeing right now. Any help is appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500049/how-to-trigger-notification-in-background

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it. I had to first move the channel notification up, as well as the notification manger before the Viewpager.registerOnPageChangeCallback call. That way I can use the notification instance to set the notification to come on at a particular time. it definitely was an if statement, but moving the first two parts up was what needed to happen. Then using module operation to have the notification show up every 20 swipes.